# un-deleted question appears to be not un-deleted

Tags: support

I un-deleted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23707891/revisions), but I've ad no views since. Is there a time period between when I undelete and when it becomes visible again?

Comment: Can we have a link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707891/java-implementing-binary-search-tree-and-overriding-iterable?noredirect=1#comment36433311_23707891

Comment: I see two sets of delete-undelete on the history of that question.

Comment: i un-deleted it twice. thought it would fix it...

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no time-period between your un-deletion and the post appearing again on the site. It might take a few moments (less than a minute) before the search indexes are updated so it becomes available as a search result again.

What you might have expected is that the question got *bumped* to the top of the active question list. [That is not the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped/48579#48579). Undeleting doesn't bump the post, mostly because that is open for abuse easily, for example by deleting and undeleting your post multiple times ;)

If you want your post to be seen by fresh eyes again you have to make an substantial edit, possible one that clarifies your question, add a test-case, include new research you have done yourself.  The ultimate way to bring a question into the spotlight in to put an bounty on it, once you have that [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)